# My Fact table has data weekly but it is not visible in SSAS cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, facttable, dimension

I have my fact table that has data in weekly basis, so I am mapping with Week dimension to pull records in Piviot table.  My ssas cube doesnt show all data that is in fact. Should I add any specific scope to show in cube.
for Example, My fact has data for week 201839 as well as 201840 (Sep month weeks)
but in cube I can see only for one week  201839 but not for 201840

Comment: Hi. Welcome to DBA SE. :) Can you query and join between them on the key that joins the fact to the dimension? Has the cube been processed since the data was updated?

Comment: Check the queries in the DSV to populate the fact and dimension. Look for any where clauses that may exclude your data.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you response. I verified by Joins with fact and dimension. It is fine. also verified the View created from Fact table.  When I query in Management studio I get data for 201840. but not in ssas browser

Comment: Has the cube been fully processed since the data was added?

Comment: Yeah, everytime I do full cube process.

Comment: Manually process "database" to ensure everything gets refreshed. All i can think of is that either a join is broken or that its not porcessed.

Comment: Make sure all filters are removed in excel and that you do a "refresh all" or even better create a new excel workbook and a new connection.

Comment: Are there any roles or profile rules that limit what your user can see?

Comment: Let me try removing the filters and refresh my pivot table. We dont have specific roles that limit the user. I am accessing via my Id, which have admin access. so that might not be the problem.

Comment: Try browsing via ssms as well it might help isolate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Create some partition. Maybe there is no partition.

Comment: Can you provide any more detail that could help the OP out?